# How do i develop a list of elements like the list of apps on Google Play or the contacts list on Whatsapp?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a app for a college project of a friend of mine. I created my project on Android Studio 1.2.2 with a minimum SDK of 10. I already worked on a database of elements on a file with a list of elements, each with certain local variables (Name, Short Description, tags, a level of popularity,the location of an icon, etc...) but i want to make scroll-able list of elements (Like for example the Google Play list of apps when you search them or the contacts list of Whatsapp) with those elements in the file. My question is how do i code something like this or which are the principles for it? I have very little experience programming apps for Android... (I have experience with Java but only the Android developer tutorials... ) I really would appreciate any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a list of scrollable items, you'll need to use a `ListView` and an `ArrayAdapter` class.

Here's a great tutorial: 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html